# No module named 'tqdm' (with same python version)

Tags: python, jupyter

When  I run this code in Jupyter Notebook:

```
import tqdm
generator, gen_optimizer = ipex.optimize(generator, optimizer=gen_optimizer)
from torch.utils.tensorboard import SummaryWriter 
writer = SummaryWriter('./log')
```

to visualize the progress of training model，it reports an error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[13], line 2
      1 ## optimizaiton with ipex
----> 2 import tqdm
      3 generator, gen_optimizer = ipex.optimize(generator, optimizer=gen_optimizer)
      4 from torch.utils.tensorboard import SummaryWriter 

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tqdm'
```

But I found that I have installed tqdm using `pip list`:
`tqdm  4.65.0`
Check the previous post, the reason may be that Jupyter notebook uses a different version of python than the one with tqdm installed, but upon checking they are the same version.
Juptyer:

```
import platform
print(platform.python_version())
>>>3.9.16
```

Terminal:

```
u203216@s001-n054:~$ python
Python 3.9.16 (main, Jun 15 2023, 02:33:25) 
[GCC 13.1.0] :: Intel Corporation on linux
(null)Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
Intel(R) Distribution for Python is brought to you by Intel Corporation.
Please check out: https://software.intel.com/en-us/python-distribution
>>> import platform
>>> print(platform.python_version())
3.9.16
```

What's reason for this problem? Any detailed answers will be appreciated.

Comment: It's a different interpreter/environment, then – the version might be same. You can just install `tqdm` in your notebook's environment with `!pip install tqdm`...

Comment: Is Jupyter Notebook using the same installation (not version!) or is it running with a venv?

Comment: @AKX · `pip install tqdm` seems no help. It stills install tqdm in another site-packages which is different from Jupyter's. When I try to install tqdm in the specified path, it reports the error:`OSError: [Errno 18] Invalid cross-device link: '/home/u203216/tmp/pip-target-uebkyo2r/lib/python/tqdm-4.66.1.dist-info' -> '/opt/intel/inteloneapi/pytorch/latest/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tqdm-4.66.1.dist-info'`   It seems that I need to change kernel, but in that case I can not use Intel's AI toolkit

Comment: @AKX you are suggesting outdated advice. Please, update your suggestions to match current best practices. You should be suggesting `%pip install tqqdm` for installing from within a running `.ipynb` file. See [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/why-users-can-install-modules-from-pip-but-not-from-conda/10722/4?u=fomightez) for more about the magic install commands added a few years ago to insure the installation occurs in the proper environment where the kernel is running that underlies the active `.ipynb` file. Use of install commands in the notebook with the exclamation point doesn't ...

Comment: <continued> insure the proper environment and can sometimes cause issues. See [the second paragraph here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/location-of-libraries-or-extensions-installed-in-jupyterlab/16303/2?u=fomightez) to get a better sense about how the exclamation point use with installs can lead to issues and confusion. (Note: At present this doesn't hold for Google Colab because what is currently used was branched off the Jupyter project before the magic install commands were added. So only use of the exclamation point with pip is possible there & it will work effectively.)

Comment: @Wayne Thanks for the clarification, I stand corrected :)

Comment: No problem, @AKX. Just trying to help everyone have a better experience by using modern stuff. A lot of old information out there, and alas the Google Colab situation isn't helping.